# Где узнать о нововведениях в javaScript?

Tags: javascript

друзья. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти актуальную информацию обо всех нововведениях в жс, начиная с 2015 года. Чтобы узнать обо всех новых функциях и деталях, которые были введены с 2015 года. Заранее большое спасибо. Книги и образовательные сайты не всегда обновляют свою информацию.

Comment: В [официальный сайт](https://tc39.es/ru/) можно, но либо я ещё не определился, либо там действительно неудобно узнать о новостях.

Comment: https://github.com/sudheerj/ECMAScript-features и https://www.quikieapps.com/blog/ecmascript/ и вообще фраза для гугла "ecmascript versions and features"

Comment: еще вариант, [State Of JS](https://stateofjs.com/ru-ru/). Можно глянуть опросы за прошлые года. Там и про фичи новые, и фреймворки, их известность. Наверное не совсем то, что ожидалось, но ресурс неплохой

Answer (score -1):

Можно с этой ссылки https://ducmanhphan.github.io/2019-03-09-The-history-of-Javascript/

А можно с этой: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript_technologies_overview